# (NSURLConnection and) retaining an iOS connection once it has been authenticated

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Is there a publicly available server connection iOS class that retains a connection between the device and a server once it has been authenticated?

An `NSURLConnection` instance is released once the connection is completed, and it's a timely process to re-authenticate every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection is intended for a single request, if you want to do multiple requests you'll likely have to go to a lower level. You could look at the [Setting Up Socket Streams](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI) section of the Streams Programming Guide, or if you don't mind going with Core Foundation instead of Cocoa you could check out the [CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Or, if all else fails, you could go with the standard BSD sockets you may be familiar with from C.